# Spring MVC 3.1.0 bug? After upgrade controllers are no more autodetected

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations, autowired

I'm writing web application that uses **Spring MVC** to bind Spring beans with REST-like channels.

I've created the configuration basic both on my previous apps (pure XML configuration) and example, which used `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` feature. I'm pointing a package with controllers with `<context:component-scan base-package="my.package"/>` in spring xml file.

It is working - in **Spring 3.0.6.RELEASE**. However, after upgrading to **3.1.0.RELEASE** my controllers stopped to be detected and no channel was registered. Spring context contains no implementation of `HelloChannel` interface.

Is this a bug in this Spring version, or I'm using deprecated configuration, which stopped to be supported in newer version? I got no error or warning, simply no bean is auto-detected.

The controller interface definition looks like that:

```
@RequestMapping("/config") public interface ConfigChannel
```

And the implementation:

```
@Controller
public class ConfigChannelImpl implements ConfigChannel
```

Comment: can you please show the code of Controller

Comment: @JigarJoshi added declaration of interface and impl

Comment: I suggest that start by setting the logging level to DEBUG, and see if that gives you some clues as to what is happening.

Comment: Do you know if the problem is that the bean is not being created, or whether mvc:annotation-driven fails to pick up your request mappings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spring documentation indicates that interface-based `@Controller`s are for proxying transactional methods. As such, you are probably using the `<tx:annotation-driven />` tag. The problem you now seem to have is that Spring 3.1 introduced support for CGLIB, a runtime-based bytecode manipulator. You need to add `proxy-target-class="true"` to your transaction configuration and add CGLIB to your classpath.

```
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />
```

From http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping

Comment: I don't need proxies at class level, I had problems with them in past so I'm now always using interfaces for proxying. I just need this interface implementation to be detected and connected to Spring MVC engine.

Comment: Still, the requirement remains. CGLIB is how Spring 3.1 manages this relationship at runtime.

Comment: Yes, your solution has worked for me. I had to add spring-tx schema and tx:annotation-driver, although I don't use it in this context. After simply adding cglib beans got detected and put into spring context, but not added to MVC servlet. Now it works and I hope I won't have any problems with proxy targetting class level.